# Detected memory leak due to "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

We are using repository implementation of hibernate in our spring boot application. While analyzing heap dump, it says that an instance of "SessionFactoryImpl" is accumulated in memory.

I tried to evict cache regions using `org.hibernate.Cache`,
    `evictDefaultQueryRegion();`
    `evictQueryRegions();`
    `evictCollectionRegion();`
    `evictAllRegions();`
but didn't give any better results

How to rectify this memory leak ?

The below screenshot shows result of heap dump
[image: Sceenshot from eclipse MAT]